# RxSwift 'bindTo(aNSButton.rx_enabled)' failed

Tags: swift, macos, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

here is my code:

```
    let aDisposeBag = DisposeBag()
    class LoginController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var accountField: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwdField: NSSecureTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var loginBtn: NSButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let accAvailable = accountField.rx_text.map({(aa)-> Bool in
            print("aa")
            return aa.characters.count > 0
        })

        let passAvailable = passwdField.rx_text.map({(aa)-> Bool in
            print("bb")
            return aa.characters.count > 0
        })

        let allAvailable = Observable.combineLatest(accAvailable, passAvailable){$0 && $1}
        allAvailable.bindTo(loginBtn.rx_enabled).addDisposableTo(aDisposeBag)

    }
}
```

When I input contents into accountField,nothing prints in the console.

But if I replace `allAvailable.bindTo(loginBtn.rx_enabled).addDisposableTo(aDisposeBag)` into

```
allAvailable.subscribeNext { (available) in
            print(available)
        }.addDisposableTo(aDisposeBag)
```

Then I can see `aa` or `bb` is printed in the console.
Anyone can tell what's wrong with my code,thanks a lot!

Comment: It works today.I don't know what happend last week.